# Help with integral over Expected Value and Indicator Function

Tags: integration, probability-theory, expected-value

I would like to know if my calculations are right. I tried to show that:

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} K_i(t)dt = E\xi_i^2$

where

$K_i(t) = E\{\xi_i (1_{0\leq t \leq \xi_i} - 1_{\xi_i\leq t < 0}) \}dt$

I got:

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} E\{\xi_i (1_{0\leq t \leq \xi_i} - 1_{\xi_i\leq t < 0}) \}dt=$
$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} t( 1_{0\leq t \leq x} - 1_{x\leq t < 0})dF_{\xi_i}(x)dt=$
$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}[\int_{0}^{x} tdt -\int_{x}^{0} tdt ]dF_{\xi_i}(x)=$
$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^2dF_{\xi_i}(x)=$
$E\xi_i^2$

Where I used Fubini once.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Application of Fubini's Theorem has to be justified.

Comment: If I proof that $t( 1_{0\leq t \leq x} - 1_{x\leq t < 0})$ is integratable, is it then fine?

Comment: Yes, that would be fine.